# Run python script at startup with Systemd service

Tags: python, systemd

I am having troubles running a python server script at startup on my RPi 3 B+.

I created a python file and placed it in `/home/pi/Desktop/scripts/bulb.py`, it contains the python interpreter should be used in the start `(#!/usr/bin/python3)` and has proper permissions `(chmod 777 bulb.py)`.

When running `/home/pi/Desktop/scripts/bulb.py` at the terminal, the server runs fine. I created a systemd service as following:

```
[Unit]
Description=The bulb server
After=network-online.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/home/pi/Desktop/scripts/bulb.py

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

and then ran `sudo systemctl enable bulbserver` in order to enable it.
However, when rebooting, it is not running and when running `systemctl status bulbserver` I can see the script is exited because of an error "ImportError: No module named 'yeelight'", I am using this module, but why when running the file from the terminal it works but when systemd tries to run it, it failes with apparently a different interpreter?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As previously mentioned, systemd services are ran by the **root** user instead of the **pi** user.  However, you can configure your .service file to run the script as a different user.

Under the **[Service]** area in your .service file, add the following line:

```
User=pi
```

Your .service file should look like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=The bulb server
After=network-online.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/home/pi/Desktop/scripts/bulb.py
User=pi

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

This line will run your script as the **pi** user, with the same permissions that the **pi** user has.

Remember to either reboot **or** run the following commands:

```
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl restart bulbserver.service
```

Comment: thanks for the solution. i solved it by installing the package to the root user by sudo pip -H install yeelight

Answer (score 0):

Startup scripts are run with user **root**, not user **pi**. This means that the directory and environment at startup are different than when you run the script when logged in as **pi**. When writing startup scripts on the Raspberry Pi, you can change the effective user to **pi** by:

```
cd /home/pi
sudo -u pi my_startup_script
```

If you want to save the output of your startup script for later reference:

```
cd /home/pi
sudo -u pi bash -c "my_startup_script >& my_startup_log"
```

You basically need another script that will run as **root** to launch your actual startup script.

Comment: No need to `cd` if you use absolute path.

Comment: Actually, startup scripts tend to have environments tied to the invocation directory instead of the script directory. I have been burned many times by not using the "cd".