# I've researched it here but I still can't get a .jar file to run at startup on a raspberry pi

Tags: boot, java

I admit I'm a complete noob at this, but I've done my homework on this site and I still can't get what I want to happen. I'm trying to get a .jar file to run at startup on a rasbpian installation. Let's call it startup.jar, it's in /home/pi/ so if I enter:

```
/usr/bin/java -jar /home/pi/startup.jar
```

at the command line, it works no matter which directory I'm in when I enter it. So from /home/pi I enter:

```
cat > startupscript << EOF
/usr/bin/java -jar /home/pi/startup.jar
EOF
```

Then I enter:

```
chmod u+x startupscript
```

Now if I go to /home/pi and type `sh startupscript` it does exactly what I want. So then I type

```
sudo nano /etc/rc.local
```

and before the exit line I add:

```
sh /home/pi/startupscript &
```

But startup.jar still doesn't start at startup.

I've also tried copying startupscript into `/etc/init.d/` and entering "sudo update-rc.d startupscript default[s, tried it with/without the s here]" but no dice.

Again, I realize this is a noob question, but what am I missing? I'm sure it's something simple.

Comment: this was just posted .... https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/84892/run-python-script-at-startup-with-systemd-service

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Run python script at startup with Systemd service](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/84892/run-python-script-at-startup-with-systemd-service)

Answer (score 1):

Make a *systemd* unit for starting your script. I do not have enough information of detailed dependencies from your python script but as template for your needs I suggest to start with:

```
rpi ~$ sudo systemctl --force --full edit myjavascript.service
```

In the editor insert these statements, save it and quit the editor:

```
[Unit]
Description=My Java Program
After=basic.target
Wants=basic.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=pi
ExecStart=/home/pi/startupscript

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Check with `systemctl cat myjavascript.service` and `systemctl status myjavascript.service`. Enable the new service with:

```
rpi ~$ sudo systemctl enable myjavascript.service
```

Reboot.

If it doesn't work please give me feedback in a comment to optimize the answer.

Comment: Thanks very much for this comment, it pointed me in the right direction. What ended up working for me was creating an autostart directory in /home/pi/.config and adding a file called myautostart.desktop that runs it with the line "Exec=sh /home/pi/startupscript". This project took me in a different way than I expected but it's working. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about java, but the language shouldn't matter. `update-rc.d` is a `SysV` command, Raspbian has been `systemd` for years. You could write a `systemd` script, but this is complex.

The simplest solution is to use `crontab` to run the job on restart.

You will find lots of similar question on this site (don't look for java but startup.
 https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/usage/cron.md shows how this can be done.

Comment: Thanks so much. I marked your comment as useful and it told me that I don't yet have enough reputation for that to matter. I appreciate you taking the time. I'll research/try this and update here how it goes. Thanks again for your reply.

Comment: Update: I tried adding "@reboot sh /home/pi/startupscript" "@reboot /usr/bin/java -jar /home/pi/startup.jar" but no dice. Eventually I got it working by adding a file to /home/pi/.config/autostart, which is working for now. Thanks again for replying to my question, I know this board sees a million variations of "can't get something to open at startup" and I appreciate you taking the time.